# MySQL distinct, group_concat and count question

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, group-concat

I have a table.

```
+----------+----------------+--------+
| orderid  | barcode        | status |
+----------+----------------+--------+
| R-R34184 | K2020101500001 |      1 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500001 |      1 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500001 |      0 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500001 |      0 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500002 |      2 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500002 |      2 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500002 |      2 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500002 |      2 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500003 |      1 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500003 |      1 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500003 |      0 |
| R-R34184 | K2020101500003 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500005 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500005 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500005 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500005 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500006 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500006 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500006 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500006 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500004 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500004 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500004 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500004 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500007 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500007 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500007 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500007 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500008 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500008 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500008 |      0 |
| R-R34185 | K2020101500008 |      0 |
+----------+----------------+--------+
```

I would like to query as follows:
DISTINCT orderby, CONCAT status and COUNT status

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+
| orderid  | status_concat | status_count |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
| R-R34184 | 0,1,2         | 3            |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
| R-R34185 | 0             | 1            |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

I tried several codes, any subquery, grouping, but it doesn't come together.
Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just `group by` and `distinct` in aggregate functions `group_concat()` and `count()`:

```
select orderid, 
    group_concat(distinct status order by status) status_concat, 
    count(distinct status) status_count
from mytable
group by orderid
```

Comment: Thanks, its OK :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `distinct`:

```
select orderid, group_concat(distinct status order by status), count(distinct status)
from t
group by orderid;
```